# How to make chrome extension to talk with angular on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angularjs-scope

I've a chrome extension which modifies the pages Dom. But the page is in angular so I need to change the scope of the element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to interact with the page's JS context from the content script. There is nothing special about AngularJS in this regard.
In order to be able to interact with the page's JS you need to inject some code into the page.
This can be achieved in a lethora of ways and **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script#answer-9517879)** covers them all in great detail.